# How to fetch value of 4’th row and 3’rd column of table using jquery

Tags: jquery

My query is "how to fetch the value of particular column of a particular row of a table using jquery".This was asked to me in a interview.

Thanks

Comment: Really? .. did you at least try first before asking?

Answer (score 2):

`:eq()` should help.

```js
var active = $("tr:eq(3) td:eq(2)");
active.addClass('active');
$('#result').text( active.text() );
```

```css
.active {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
result: <span id="result"></span>
```

Reference: [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe `:eq()` is 0 index

```
var value = $('table')
              .find('tr:eq(3)') // get the 4th table row
              .find('td:eq(4)') // get the 5th table cell in that row
              .text();          // get the text inside that cell
```

There are many ways to write the above selector but i wrote it this way to show the steps.

Comment: then should't it be td:eq(2) for column ?

Comment: `tr` are rows, `td` are cells or (columns) in this case

Comment: @Manish I added some comments to explain the process

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(3)").html();
```